# Spyder Console Throws "[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ipython, spyder

I am new to Python and use Spyder as my IDE, and I mainly use it for data analysis. A few days ago I reinstalled Spyder for some reasons. Now when I want to directly enter pandas-related commands such as `df.info()` or `df.describe()` in the iPython console, I see the error message after the output (I do get the right output though). It shows:

```
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
    await result
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 798, in inspect_request
    reply_content = self.do_inspect(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 555, in do_inspect
    bundle = self.shell.object_inspect_mime(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1838, in object_inspect_mime
    return self.inspector._get_info(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/oinspect.py", line 738, in _get_info
    info_dict = self.info(obj, oname=oname, info=info, detail_level=detail_level)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/oinspect.py", line 838, in info
    if info and info.parent and hasattr(info.parent, HOOK_NAME):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1466, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Weirdly, this only shows up when I attempt to type the commands manually, and only when I use pandas-related commands. When I run the commands from scripts, or even simply use the up arrow key to select commands in the console, the error message won't show; It only shows when I manually type the commands.

I've looked the error up on the internet but found no discussion. How do I deal with this error?

I reinstalled Spyder, Python, iPython, ipykernel, spyder-kernels, but nothing seemed to help.

Comment: can you please provide more details about your current setup? Hardware, OS, Spyder/Python/Pandas version, etc.? It can help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Having same issue. Looks like bug has been reported: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/20816

Comment: Thanks, I guess we'll just have to wait. I will update once the problem is fixed.

Comment: I get this error when calling `df.head()` the first time on a dataframe created by reading an `.xlsx` file with pandas.  I have gotten it for multiple dataframes (created from different files), but I never get the error on subsequent calls to `df.head()`.

Answer (score 3):

Same here. New-ish install of Spyder with the following setup details:

- Spyder 5.4.2 standalone
- Miniconda environment with Python 3.9.16, Pandas 1.5.3, and spyder-kernels 2.4.2
- Windows 11 22H2 (OS build 22621.1485)
- Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme with i7/3050Ti/32GB/1TB

Some observations:

- it also happens with Series methods, e.g., `df["column"].min()`
- the `ValueError` message says "truth of a **DataFrame** is ambiguous" vs the **Series** error I see more commonly; not sure if this could help with troubleshooting
- there's NO error when using different slicing methods

The 3rd point above does offer a workaround, if not a true solution (hence me posting as an answer versus comment). Specifically, `df.loc[rows, columns].<method>` works without issue. This would mean a DataFrame method like `describe` would be implemented as `df.loc[:, :].describe()`.

Answer (score 3):

A stopgap solution is provided on the [Spyder GitHub](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/20816) page where the bug was reported:

```
conda activate <your_environment>
conda install ipython=8.7
```

Obviously downgrading isn't ideal for the long run, but it does resolve the issue until it is formally patched.

Comment: confirmed, stopgap works. be sure to restart your kernel if Spyder is open when you run this. I'm on Spyder 5.4.3.

Comment: temp solution worked for me; also on spyder 5.4.3; macOS 13.2.1; Anaconda 2.4.2

FYI: "The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:"
  ipython 8.12.0 --> 8.7.0 | krb5 1.20.1 --> 1.19.4 | libpq 12.15 --> 12.9 | openssl 3.0.9 --> 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade ipython
```

upgraded IPython to 8.14 and removed the issue. Make sure that you use the right pip (conda/bin/pip).

At the time of writing, the IPython conda package is version 8.12. Once updated, the answer should be: `conda update ipython`.